# php preg_split by semi-colons not found between opening and closing brackets

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-split

I'm writing a recursive function and I'm getting into trouble on the regular expression part...

hopefully one of you kind people can help...

give a single string with contents such as below...

```
setDynamicFields=[product_model=1;attribute_id=10];setDynamicFields=[product_model=1;attribute_id=10];joinTable=suppliers;
```

I need to split this by semi-colons however I need to ignore those semi-colons found between [ and ] i.e. `setDynamicFields=[product_model=1;attribute_id=10]` should be split out in tact so I can set `setDynamicFields` as a key and `[product_model=1;attribute_id=10]` as a value

I've tried the following...

```
$fields = preg_split("/(\b(?!=[\[])[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\b(?![\]]))/",$line);

$fields = preg_split("/(?!=\[)(;)(?!\])/",$line);
```

Not having much luck :-(

Any takers?

many thanks,

Robert

Comment: what if you split it by ]; not only semi-colon?

Comment: hi Darka. in case some entries are of the format a=b;b=2; and don't have brackets... I need something that'll cover both eventualities. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> split by semi-colons not found between opening and closing brackets

If the brackets are always balanced and you want to split you can use a regex like:

```
;(?![^][]*\])
```

In PHP written something like:

```
$fields = preg_split('/;(?![^][]*\])/', $line);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
/([^;]*)?=(\[.+?\])|([^;]*?)=(.*?);/g
```

See the [example@regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uF4eC2).

The `g`-flag is only necessary if your input is not on one line.
Also, don't use `preg_split` for this, use `preg_match_all`, see [this demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/2Vl) (be sure to hit preg_match_all on the right) for the results. See [the manual for `preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) for further infos regarding the usage.

This will cover both eventualities in your input string: the `[]` being present or not.

Comment: i created something similar [^;]+=\[.+?\];|[^;]+=[^;]+?;

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
.*?(\[.*?\])?;
```

This will match everything up to a semi-colon, optionally consuming anything that exists in square brackets until the next semi-colon is found